# I need an algorithm to look through 3 lists and find unique items

Tags: algorithm, list, language-agnostic

I've been scratching my head for a couple of hours and could use some help...

I have 3 lists of objects. Each list can contain the same objects (but doesn't have to). I want an algorithm to test if there is at least one unique object in each list.

EDIT: An item can only be in each list once, but can be in more than one list.

EDIT: there is a pseudo 4th list - 1 item from each of the 3 lists. THAT is the list which must contain uniques. There could be 3 items overall, each in each list. That should return true, as the 4th list could contain uniques.

EDIT: This is what I came up with so far, but I don't know how efficient this is, or even if it works!

```
bool Uniques( List<Item> list1, List<Item> list2, List<Item> list3 ) {
    foreach( Item item1 in list1 ) {
        foreach( Item item2 in list2 ) {
            if ( item1!=item2 ) {
                foreach( Item item3 in list3 ) {
                    if ( item3!=item1 && item3!=item2 ) return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: To illustrate, here's an example.
From an overall list of colours: Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Cyan, Magenta, White, Black, Orange, Purple.

List 1 contains Red, Green
List 2 contains Red
List 3 contains Blue, Orange
results in FALSE

List 1 contains Red, Green
List 2 contains Red, Green
List 3 contains Red, Green
results in FALSE

List 1 contains Red, Green
List 2 contains Yellow
List 3 contains Red, Green
results in TRUE

Comment: Add them all to a set?

Comment: Does "unique" mean that it's only present once in its list, it's only present in one list, or both?

Comment: How efficient does the solution need to be?  Any restrictions on using extra space?

Comment: Would be good to be pretty efficient time-wise, but there won't be hundreds of items in each list so don't think space will be too much of an issue.

Comment: I suppose there's an error in 'item3!=item1 && item3!=item1' :)

Comment: "Unique" means that the 3 chosen items, 1 from each list, form a 4th list and they are unique in that list.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand your question.  Could you please provide a few different test cases (each with three input lists and the output you expect the algorithm to answer), to show what you mean?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I'm essentially changing my answer due to misunderstanding of the original question.

Since we know that each list element is unique in its list, then we can use the following algorithm:

```
Compute the length of the three lists.
Sort these lengths into a tuple (l_1,l_2,l_3) in ascending order.

If l_1 >= 1 and l_2 >= 2 and l_3 >= 3, then answer 'YES'; 
else, 
    if among all possible combinations there is a valid one, 
    then, return 'YES', 
    otherwise return 'NO'.
```

This algorithm takes **constant time** if you know the lengths of the lists in advance (otherwise it's linear). Observe that in the case when you examine all possible combinations you examine less than 6 triples.

Now, the proof that this works is very simple: choose an element `x_1` from the list of length `l_1`, then choose an element `x_2` from the list of length `l_2`, different from `x_1` (this is possible since `l_2 >= 2`). Now, choose an element `x_3` from the list of length `l_3`, different from `x_1` and `x_2`. Again, you can choose such an element since the list has at least three distinct elements.

I hope that now I actually solved the problem you were asking for.

Comment: As I've commented elsewhere though, a valid unique item CAN BE on 2 lists. It's the combination I'm interested in: IF any combination of 3 items, 1 from each list, each different from each other, can be made, then return true. So in a way there's a 4th list, made up of any 1 item from list 1, any 1 item from list 2, and any 1 item from list 3. It's THAT list which has to contain uniques.

Comment: OK, I completely remade my approach this time.

Comment: What is funny about my edited answer, is that it proves that **your** algorithm takes **constant time** and that it's correct.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense! Am I right in thinking the second part is essentially the same as the code in the question, but the important part you've added is a prior check on list lengths that would quickly de-necessitate the thorough check?

Comment: Mind you, the thorough check would quickly discover uniques even without the prior check, am I right? In any case, you've cleared things up for me very nicely! Thanks!

Comment: Voilà, that's it. 

And I recommend you read the proof carefully and you will realize that your algorithm will stop in at most 6 steps. My real contribution is the proof. My pseudocode will perform about as good as yours. Maybe a little better if you precompute the lists' lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Linear time: Use hashes. First hash each elt of list 1 to an array of three booleans, setting the first bool to true. Repeat for lists 2 and 3. Voila -- you have a hash whose keys are the elements and whose values indicate which list(s) each element belongs to.

Then, to see if there is at least one unique item in each list, loop through the hash values, checking for arrays where just one of the three bools is set to true. E.g., if a value is [true, true, false] you ignore it, but if one is [false, true, false] then you know the second list has a unique item.

Comment: I understand that, but how do I then determine if there is at least one unique item in each list? It doesn't matter if the item is in 2 or 3 lists: only that there exists, overall, at least 1 item in each list and they are all different from each other. For instance, there could be 3 items, each of them on all 3 lists. That should generate a TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

```
set counter = 0
create empty list U
for each list L
    create D, a duplicate of list L
    for each list P, where P != L
        remove all items in P from D

    add all items in D to U
    if D is not empty, increment counter


if counter == number of lists, return U, else return empty list
```

The list returned will be non empty if and only if each list contains a value that is not in any of the other lists. If it is empty, it is the set of such unshared values.

Comment: Each item can be legally on 2 or 3 lists though. I believe it's been sorted now, and is pretty much as I've put above unless I'm missing something. Thanks!